# Do shaken, frightened, and panicked replace each other or stack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, conditions, fear

The conditions [shaken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Shaken), [frightened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Frightened), and [panicked](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Panicked) are related fear effects. Does only the worst condition apply because of this, or would being shaken and panicked give you a -4 on stuff?

I ask because there are lots of ways to end up with one of the conditions, and many effects talk about increasing the effect, but I havent seen any rules that say you can only be in one state of fear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The cumulative effects of fear are better defined in Special Abilities on [Fear](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/special-abilities#TOC-Fear). The main point is this:

> Fear effects are cumulative. A shaken character who is made shaken again becomes frightened, and a shaken character who is made frightened becomes panicked instead. A frightened character who is made shaken or frightened becomes panicked instead.

It's unfortunate that these cumulative effects aren't clearer in the descriptions of the conditions [shaken](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Shaken), [frightened](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Frightened), and [panicked](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/conditions#TOC-Panicked).

Comment: That is good to know, and also makes creating the spreadsheet effects much easier.